# How To Block The UserName After 3 Invalid Password Attempts IN ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I used the following code for checking user name and password. and I want ti block the user name after 3 invalid password attempt. what should I add in my codeing

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        Byte[] hashedDataBytes;
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        hashedDataBytes = md5hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(TextBox3.Text));
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hashedDataBytes.Length * 2);
        foreach (Byte b in hashedDataBytes)
        {
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        }
        string hash = hex.ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Shihab-PC;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=SOMETHING;Password=SOMETHINGELSE");
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select password from Users where UserId='" + TextBox4.Text + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds, "Users");

    SqlDataAdapter ad2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select UserId from Users ", con);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    ad2.Fill(ds2, "Users");
    Session["id"] = TextBox4.Text.ToString();


    if ((string.Compare((ds.Tables["Users"].Rows[0][0].ToString()), hash)) == 0)
    {
        if (string.Compare(TextBox4.Text, (ds2.Tables["Users"].Rows[0][0].ToString())) == 0)
        {
                            Response.Redirect("actioncust.aspx");

        }
        else
        {

            Response.Redirect("actioncust.aspx");


        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Text = "Invalid Login";
    }

    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: Don't use MD5.  Instead, use SHA512.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: You need to salt your hashes.

Comment: Your second SQL query is totally wrong.

Comment: In summary, **don't do crypto yourself**.

Comment: Before that, start using SQL parameters while interacting with the database. Else, the opportunist won't even need a third or fourth attempt.. :)

Comment: I used this coding in my project. I cant change and I have to use md5

Comment: Also, you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: This code is one of the biggest sets of security vulnerabilities around.  **DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN YOUR PROJECT**!!!  Remember [Gawker](http://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/12/13/gawker-passwords-hacked-what-you-should-do/) (which was already much more secure than this)

Comment: Im new in ASP.net and is the first time I use encryption and dont know what to change and what to remove and what to add. can you explain in more detail

Comment: Do not do this yourself _at all_ until you know a lot more than you do now.  Writing secure code is _hard_.  Instead, use prebuilt 3rd-party components, such as ASP.Net membership.

Comment: @shihab I have already provided you with a link of ASP.Net membership

Answer (score 7):

You should use [ASP.Net membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), which does this out-of-the-box and is actually secure.

Comment: Not with your code.  Your code is one of the biggest sets of security vulnerabilities around.  **DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN YOUR PROJECT**!!!

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks has suggested it's better if you use  [ASP.Net membership](http://www.asp.net/moving-to-aspnet-20/tutorials/membership). There's a lots of tutorials on web, if you search for them in Google.

Secondly you don't have to write two queries.

You could use `Select UserId from Users where UserId=@id and password=@pass` and then use count property of dataset